# Comparar duas tabelas no mysql agrupando a tabela principal e listando o resultado da segunda tabela

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, slimframework

Olá! vou explicar desdo principio.. Estou comparando as seguintes tabelas `accounts` com `clientes`
 o select usa o `user_id` para encontra todos os clientes com mesmo `users_id2` na tabela `clientes` como descrito abaixo, até ai esta certo!

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts as a INNER JOIN clientes as c ON (a.user_id=c.users_id2)"
```

mas esta a me retorna esse resultado (repetindo o user_id)...

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "100001",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "clientes": {
            "id_cliente" => "1",
            "users_id": "100001",
            "nome_pessoa": "cliente pereira"
        }
    },
    {
        "user_id": "100001",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "clientes": {
            "id_cliente" => "2",
            "users_id": "100001",
            "nome_pessoa": "cliente Gustavo"
        }
    }
]
```

E preciso que retorne um resultado mais preciso agrupando o `user_id` e abaixo exibindo todos os clientes listados.. que no json ficaria exatamente assim..

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "100001",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "clientes": {
            "0": {
                 "id_cliente" => "1",
                 "users_id": "100001",
                 "nome_pessoa": "cliente pereira"
            },
            "1": {
                 "id_cliente" => "2",
                 "users_id": "100001",
                 "nome_pessoa": "cliente Gustavo"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Então Como posso estar escrevendo esse código no mysql? eu tentei `GROUP BY user_id`
mas foi sem sucesso..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa minha resposta não é uma solução em MySql mas acredito que resolva seu problema.

Na documentação do Laravel há um recurso chamado [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), com ele você pode buscar valores de uma tabela pegando também os valores da relação sem sofrer o problema N+1.

Você primeiro precisaria definir as relações na Model do User.

```
/**
 * Define que usuários pertence a vários clientes.
 */
public function clientes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clientes');
}
```

E depois você faria a busca pelos clientes dos usuários usando:

```
$users = App\User::with('clientes')->get();
```

E caso queira exibir da forma como mencionado, talvez você possa dar uma olhada no [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) do Laravel, ele auxilia a retornar um formato Json personalizado da forma que você definir.

Comment: Funcionou tudo ok Vinicius , realmente oque eu precisava Obrigado!